# @media screen css property not working

Tags: css, screen, media

I added `@media screen` css in an effort to change my website but it doesn't seem to be responding. I added  meta `name = "viewport" content="width=1200, width=device-width"` to the HTML and that was the only thing that effected the way my site looks on my phone. In the CSS I added the following but it has no effect.

```
@media screen
and (max-device-width: 768px)
and (orientation: portrait) {
   body {
   max-width: 600px;
}
   #sidebar {
     width: 0;
   }
}

@media screen
and (max-device-width: 1000px)
and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    max-width: 800px;
  }
    #sidebar {
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

So how do I:

- Get this to work, is my CSS wrong?
- Is there a way to specifically get rid of the `#sidebar` in `@media screen` css?

Comment: `display:none;` is better than `width:0;`. But your code still should work.

Comment: can u give a link of the website where you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This (Not Tested)

```
@media handheld and (orientation: landscape), 
  screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

 body {
    max-width: 800px;
  }

 #sidebar {
    width: 0;
 }

}
```

Comment: well it should work so either something wrong somewhere else or try using EM's and make a fiddle

Comment: So what was the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that an old version of your CSS file (before your changes) has been cached by your phone. If you have PHP, a nice way to get around this is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?ver=<?php print filemtime('styles.css') ?>">
```

That way, the stylesheet is only redownloaded when it needs to be.

If you don't have PHP, you can always just change the `?ver=` paramater by hand each time you make a change in your CSS file.

This may or may not be your problem, I don't know. But it might help.

Comment: No I deleted the cookies and history on safari and than also tried it on my dad's. The CSS is correct though right?

Comment: Yeah I think so... and it's cache you'd be wanting to delete, not cookies and history.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks alright to me. Have you tried to do a hard refresh?

shft + f5 to my experiences fixes CSS when you don't notice a setting applied. Also deleting the cache helps too!

Also to get rid of #sidebar

```
#sidebar{
    display:none;
}
```

will hide it when you hit your @media.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yea I deleted my cache on my phone and computer and it appears to have had no effect. Thanks for the #sidebar bit I have that else where in my code I should have figured to put it there. Is there anything else in my html that I need to add maybe?

Comment: I changed the sidebar bit and that got rid of it. Thank you it's funny elsewhere in my code I did that but totally forgot it here.

Comment: It appears that I needed to get rid of content="width=1200". On Chrome mobile the desire width was achieved on Safari mobile it was not perfect but good enough for now. I'll continue to tinker with it. Isn't @media screen suppose to work on laptops and PCs as well?

Answer (score 0):

@media works for everything. e.g my phone has a width of 720px for eg. when you have CSS @media for mobile at 720px; the following CSS will apply if that makes sense. Should read on mobile first responsive design if that's what you're trying to achieve, but that's a whole different topic. As for the code in your @media, you are targeting mobile devices, not laptops/computers. Incase you're not aware of that. so if I'm thinking right the CSS will apply only to mobile devices. For laptops/pc, @media (max-width: xxxpx) {} would do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Akira Dawson for the display portion. It appears that I needed to get rid of content="width=1200" for it to display properly on my iPhone. In addition what I ultimately did was got rid of @media screen and changed it to @media handheld for it to take effect on my iPhone. For whatever reason @media screen would not work. It's interesting because I was told @media handheld doesn't work on the iPhone but apparently it does.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it `content="width=1200` says that your site needs a viewport of *at least* 1200px which is contrary to `max-device-width: 768px`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />` should probably fix your problem.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag